# What would the conjugation of the verb "to better" be in this sentence snippet: "... for the purposes of bettering my..."

Tags: verbos, conjugación

> I have written this Spanish text for the purposes of bettering my Spanish speaking and writing abilities.

How would one conjugate *mejorar* in this case? Would one even use *mejorar* in this case? I'm thinking *mejorando*, but that seems a bit unfit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually (I'm not certain if always though) what is expressed by means of a gerund form inside a prepositional phrase in English, corresponds to the infinitive in Spanish (in prepositional phrase)...

"for the purposes of **bettering**" → "con el propósito de **mejorar**"

"for **improving** my Spanish" → "para **mejorar** mi español"

Comment: Aha, I see. My google document did auto-correct it to *mejorar*, so that's in alignment.